# Why does non-dimensionalization work?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know the steps to do the same. But I do not understand why does it work. Why is that non-dimensionalising an ODE gives us a function with much fewer parameters. What's the intuitive sense here behind this approach?

Comment: If you change the length units from meters to feet, the equations can only change so much. If they depended on all the physical parameters directly then "too much" would change.

Comment: Why would the ODE decide to not depend on the dimensionless variables? A variable is still a variable, dimensionless or not. So, can you please elaborate your point?

Comment: If I change the length unit by multiplying it by 2, the equation should respond by dividing any quantities with length $^k $ in their units by $2^k $. I can exploit this by multiplying by just the right thing so that a quantity in the equation becomes 1. For example I can look at $dx/dt=kx $, introduce scales $x_C $ and $t_C $, then $dy/ds=kt_C y$. So I can remove $k $ from the problem by choosing my time unit to be $1/k $; this is like measuring time for radioactive decay in units of half-lives. I can do better by choosing $x_C=x_0$ so that you just have $y=e^s $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the idea is that numbers with units must necessarily respond in a simple way when we change our system of units. If, say, I change the basic unit of length to be twice as big, then all numbers with $\text{length}^k$ in their units will get divided by $2^k$ accordingly.

As a result of this, we can *choose* our system of units to entirely cancel certain parameters from the problem. Essentially the simplest possible example is $y'=ky,y(0)=y_0$. In this case we can introduce characteristic length $y_C$ and characteristic time $t_C$ with $y=y_C x,t=t_C s$. This converts the equation to

$$\frac{y_C}{t_C} \frac{dx}{ds} = k y_C x,x(0)=y_0/y_C.$$

Now again, I can pick $y_C,t_C$ to be whatever I want depending on my purposes, but a natural choice is $y_C=y_0,t_C=1/k$, so that the equation becomes

$$\frac{dx}{ds} = x,x(0)=1.$$

In reality $k$ and $y_0$ are still in the problem but they only reappear when we go back to express the solution of the problem in terms of some other system of units.